# Understanding new modules creating and importing in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I need help with importing my own new module. Module dinspect is in the directory modules:

```
import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('../modules'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
>>output:
../modules\dinspect.ipynb
../modules\test.ipynb
../modules\.ipynb_checkpoints\dinspect-checkpoint.ipynb
../modules\.ipynb_checkpoints\test-checkpoint.ipynb
```

Importing the module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../modules')

from modules import dinspect

>>output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-a2eb8b155959> in <module>
----> 1 from modules import dinspect

ImportError: cannot import name 'dinspect' from 'modules' (unknown location)
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. first i should convert my jupyter notebook to py script
2. second as i have several files in the modules dir i should add the **init**.py file
3. so i did that:

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to script dinspect.ipynb __init__.ipynb
>>output
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook dinspect.ipynb to script
[NbConvertApp] Writing 2181 bytes to dinspect.py
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook __init__.ipynb to script
[NbConvertApp] Writing 52 bytes to __init__.py
```

Thus after that my module dinspect successfully imported!